Formatear ZonedDateTime en un endpoint
Estoy montando una api con SpringBoot y tengo el problema de que en un response que tiene una variable de tipo ZonedDateTime no consigo que su salida cumpla el formato 2024-08-03T15:50:30+02:00. Me devuelve el formato 2024-08-03T15:50:30.275Z y con eso no soy capaz de saber a qué zona horaria pertenece, y me lo está reconociendo como +00:00 (dos horas por detrás de lo que debería).
Creo que podría formatear dentro del response la instancia del tiempo a un String, pero esa solución me valdría unicamente para ese response, y me gustaría crear una especie de adaptador para que en cualquier response que se enviase una instancia de ZonedDateTime utilizase el formato que indico.
En el cliente android que me estoy montando, es tan fácil como montar un adaptador para que me lo convierta el solo, y siempre que me llega una variable con ese tipo lo formatea correctamente, pero aquí estoy perdido y no se como hacerlo.
He probado a establecer la localización por si fuera eso, pero el formato sigue siendo el mismo. El bean utilizado es:
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfig {
    @Bean
    LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        return slr;
    }
}

Gracias de antemano

Agrega lo que trataste e investigaste, me parece que solo debes definir un Locale.

@Jorgesys he creado un bean que devuelve el LocaleResolver en una clase de configuración pero sigue devolviendo el mismo formato incorrecto

Agrega el código a tu pregunta

Acabo de actualizar la pregunta original con el bean que comentabas @Jorgesys

Gracias @Jorgesys, tu respuesta no iba mal encaminada. Tengo la API en un contenedor docker al cual no le había definido la zona. Al ponerle la variable de entorno correspondiente ya me devuelve el formato correcto, sin necesidad de definir el Bean anterior
